# How to reduce a literal object based on certain conditions?

Tags: javascript

I have the following task, having an array of objects with this structure

```
{
    fullName: 'Some Name',
    datashow: '1',
    classroom: 'C101',
    audio: true,
    cpu: false,
    internet: false,
    pointer: true,
    screen: false,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    blocks: '1,2'
}
```

And need to transform it into this:

```
{
    audio: true,
    pointer: true,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
}
```

Following these conditions:

1. The keys and values for fullName, datashow, classroom and blocks should not appear
2. The remaining keys and values must appear only if its value is true

Right now i am using this solution currently works this way but I would like a faster and more elegant solution:

```
function reduceActivity(activity) {
    const newObject = {};

    for (key in activity) {
        if (key !== 'fullName' && key !== 'datashow' && key !== 'blocks' ) {
            if (activity[key]) {
                newObject[key] = activity[key];
            }
        }
    }

    return newObject;
}
```

Thanks for any help or recommendation

Comment: why is `description` included and not `classroom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution. About performance there is no actual changes, you don't need to worry about that in this case, but in this solution you are giving the `keys` which must be excluded into the array and use the array to check the keys.

```js
const obj = {
    fullName: 'Some Name',
    datashow: '1',
    classroom: 'C101',
    audio: true,
    cpu: false,
    internet: false,
    pointer: true,
    screen: false,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    blocks: '1,2'
};

const excludeKeys = ['fullName', 'datashow', 'blocks', 'classroom'];

const mappedObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((o, item) => {

  if( !excludeKeys.includes(item) && obj[item]) {
      o[item] = obj[item];
  }
  
  return o;

}, {});

console.log(mappedObj);
```

With your solution in this code

`for(key in activity)`

you may have some logic issues if your object will have an `prototype` with it's properties. That `key in activity` will also give you prototypes properties which are enumerable.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Suren, and the observation. Simple and elegant solution

Comment: @user615274 No Problem

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the check if a key should be ignored. Then check it ans well as the check for the proerties value and return early.

```
function reduceActivity(activity) {
    var ignoreKeys = { fullName: true, classroom: true, datashow: true, blocks: true },
        newObject = {};

    Object.keys(activity).forEach(function (key) {
        if (ignoreKeys[key] || !activity[key]) {
            return;
        }
        newObject[key] = activity[key];
    });
    return newObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late........

```js
var fields =['classroom', 'audio', 'cpu', 'internet','pointer','screen','description']
var arr = [
    {
        fullName: 'Some Name',
        datashow: '1',
        classroom: 'C101',
        audio: true,
        cpu: false,
        internet: false,
        pointer: true,
        screen: false,
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        blocks: '1,2'
    },
    {
        fullName: 'Some Name',
        datashow: '1',
        classroom: 'C101',
        audio: true,
        cpu: false,
        internet: false,
        pointer: true,
        screen: false,
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        blocks: '1,2'
    },
        {
        fullName: 'Some Name',
        datashow: '1',
        classroom: false,
        audio: false,
        cpu: false,
        internet: false,
        pointer: false,
        screen: false,
        description: false,
        blocks: '1,2'
    }
    ]
    
var ret = arr.reduce((acc, obj)=>{

  var o={}
  fields.forEach(f => {
    if (obj[f] === true || obj[f].length > 0 || obj[f] === 0) o[f]=obj[f]
   })

   if(Object.keys(o).length === 0) 
    return acc
   else
    acc.push(o)
   return acc
},[])
console.log(ret)
```